# ffmpeg doesn't start recording when using segments

Tags: debian, ffmpeg

I've got ffmpeg under Debian Wheezy and I'm trying to record a few cameras around the office in one hour blocks over 24 hours.

When I type the following command it records without a problem;

```
ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i http://<user>:<pass>@192.168.200.220/video/mjpg.cgi -acodec copy -vcodec copy ~/data/temp.mp4
```

When I try the following command which includes the segments it doesn't start recording.

```
ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i http://<user>:<pass>@192.168.200.220/video/mjpg.cgi -acodec copy -vcodec copy -y -f segment -segment_time 3600 -segment_wrap 24 ~/data/temp%03d.mp4
```

Here is the full error;

```
ffmpeg version 1.0.10 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 25 2014 07:50:40 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --dis  libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
  libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
  libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
  libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
  libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000
[mjpeg @ 0x1750e60] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'http://<user>:<password>@192.168.200.220/video/mjpg.cgi':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, segment, to '/home/map7/data/temp3.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
Received signal 2: terminating.
```

I have tried different settings for max_analyze_duration with no luck

**Update**

Trying with ffmpeg 3.0

This works

```
docker run jrottenberg/ffmpeg -i http://<user>:<pass>@192.168.200.220/video/mjpg.cgi -f mjpeg - > /media/data/temp%03d.mp4
```

I've also got the segments to work a little better but have hit another problem;

docker run -v /media/data:/data jrottenberg/ffmpeg -i http://:@192.168.200.220/video/mjpg.cgi -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_wrap 24 /data/temp%03d.mpeg

I now get the follow issues;

```
[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=39 size=343ate=N/A speed=0.153x    
[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=229 size=332te=N/A speed=0.152x    
[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=1323 size=13091N/A speed=0.151x    
[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=3352 size=13091
[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=5393 size=13091
[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=7434 size=13091
[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=9475 size=13091
[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=11516 size=13091
[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=457 size=536te=N/A speed=0.151x    
[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=81 size=270ate=N/A speed=0.15x     
^C[mpeg @ 0x2fea340] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 130KB15x    
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
```

It does output something now though.

Comment: That's an old version. Update it to the current nightly. Also, Output #0 name is wrong and should have three numeral digits?

Comment: You can download it from http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ (for 2.6.32 and newer kernels).